# Плавный скроллинг страницы. Не к якорю, не к элементу, а просто плавный скроллинг. Как в IE.

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Не подскажете код, скрипт или еще что, чтобы страница прокручивалась плавно? Если учитывать, что из знаний JavaScript у меня только вставка кода в страницу)) Премного благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="#bottom">ЗАКАЗАТЬ СЕЙЧАС</a>

$(document).ready(function() {

        $('a[href=#bottom]').click(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:2430}, 'slow');
            return false;
        });

    });
```

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/top.js"></script>

так подключается, лучше скрипт выносить в отдельный файл
Где 2430 задаете свое

Comment: Это для плавной прокрутки вверх, или вообще по странице?

Когда крутишь колесико мыши, страница прокручивается рывками. Мне нужно чтобы было плавно